# vue-authenticate library throwing error in Vue.js

Tags: oauth

I'm completely stuck and I'm sure this isn't as complicated as I am making it.

I am using the [vue-authenticate](https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate) library for Instagram login.

Inside my **main.js** I have:

```
Vue.use(VueAuthenticate, {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000', // Your API domain
  providers: {
    instagram: {
      clientId: '******',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/auth' // Your client app URL
    }
  }
})
```

Inside of **store.js** I have:

```
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import { VueAuthenticate } from 'vue-authenticate'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

const vueAuth = new VueAuthenticate(Vue.prototype.$http, {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
})
```

And this is my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="index columns">
    <button @click="authenticate('instagram')">Login with Instagram</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>    
export default {
  name: 'Index',
  methods: {
    authenticate (provider) {
      this.$auth.authenticate(provider)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When you click the button it takes you to Instagram and authenticates you. It hits my Rails API endpoint which I am seeing on the server.

However, when it redirects back to my Vue.js app I just get `Error: Authentication failed at eval` error.

I'm stumped as to what the issue is. Has anyone run into this issue or can you see an issue with my set-up?

Comment: Have you ever found the cause? We are running into the exact same issue.